# multi step form wizard jquery in joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

i create a view in joomla, and i create a multi step form wizard in jquery  and set in view of joomla. but when i click on continue button next step not working. i remove $ in code and add jQuery words but not happening.
please help.

my code in joomla

```
 <section id="sp-page-title"><div class="row"><div id="sp-title" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"><div class="sp-column "></div></div></div></section>
<section id="sp-main-body">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <section>
    <div class="wizard">
        <div class="wizard-inner">
            <div class="connecting-line"></div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <form role="form">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                    <h3>Step 1</h3>
                    <p>This is step 1</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                    <h3>Step 2</h3>
                    <p>This is step 2</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                    <h3>Step 3</h3>
                    <p>This is step 3</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
                    <h3>Complete</h3>
                    <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
 </section>
</div>
</div>
 </section>
```

> and i create myjquery.js: -

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
//Initialize tooltips
$('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

//Wizard
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

    var $target = $(e.target);

    if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }
});

$(".next-step").click(function (e) {

    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
    nextTab($active);

});
$(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    prevTab($active);

});
});

function nextTab(elem) {
$(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
$(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
```

> and css:-

```
  .wizard {
margin: 20px auto;
background: #fff;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs {
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.wizard > div.wizard-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.connecting-line {
height: 2px;
background: #e0e0e0;
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active >  a:hover, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
color: #555555;
cursor: default;
border: 0;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
line-height: 70px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 100px;
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tab i{
color:#555555;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid #5bc0de;

}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab i{
color: #5bc0de;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
color: #333;
border: 2px solid #333;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
left: 46%;
opacity: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
bottom: 0px;
border: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
left: 46%;
opacity: 1;
margin: 0 auto;
bottom: 0px;
border: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
margin: 20px auto;
border-radius: 100%;
padding: 0;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
    background: transparent;
}

.wizard .tab-pane {
position: relative;
padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
margin-top: 0;
}

@media( max-width : 585px ) {

.wizard {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto !important;
}

span.round-tab {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
}
}
```

Comment: Wizard jQuery ?

Comment: What errors are thrown?

Comment: when i click save and continued button, form not going to next step.

Comment: That doesn't answer if any errors are thrown in browser console. Create a basic demo that reproduce this

Comment: Why not use RS Forms for that? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: ok, i will try in RS forms.